# How to Get the list of all User Accounts of Windows in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, user-accounts, wmic

I have two types of user accounts on my computer i.e. local users and domain users. I am trying to get the list of all users in all domains. I am using the following code in C#

```
   string sPath = "WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer";
                using (var computerEntry = new DirectoryEntry(sPath))
                    foreach (DirectoryEntry childEntry in computerEntry.Children)
                        if (childEntry.SchemaClassName == "User")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(childEntry.Name);
    
                        }
```

But I am only getting the local users, not domain users. What would be the better solution ?

Comment: `"WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName` looks for local accounts, not domains

Comment: @Panagiotis then how can I get all the accounts including local accounts and domain account ?